# In R, how do I fill elements of a vector conditionally with respect to elements of another vector of equal length?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector, `purity`, which contains the purities (as character strings) of 10,000 gold nuggets.

```
purity <- sample(c("pure","high","medium","low"), 10000, replace = TRUE)
```

I would like to generate a second vector, '`coef`', such that the value of element n in `coef` is dependent on the value of element n in `purity`, with "pure," "high,""medium," and "low" in `purity` corresponding to 1.0, 0.8, 0.5, and 0.2, in `coef`, respectively.

Below is a pair of vectors, both manually generated and length=5, illustrating my goal.

```
    > purity <- c("medium", "high", "low", "high", "pure")
    > coef   <- c( 0.5,      0.8,    0.2,   0.8 ,   1.0)     #spaces added for legibility
    > purity
    [1] "medium" "high"   "low"    "high"   "pure"     
    > coef
    [1] 0.5 0.8 0.2 0.8 1.0
```

How do I automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `match` or a named vector for replacement.  The `purity` and `coef` are the `key/value` pairs that are used to match with the longer vector 'purity1'.  When we use `setNames`, it creates a named vector on the coef, which will be used in matching with the corresponding values of 'purity1' to return the values 'coef' corresponding to that match.

```
out <- unname(setNames(value, key)[purity])
```

-checking the output

```
> head(purity)
[1] "low"    "pure"   "pure"   "low"    "medium" "high"  
> head(out)
[1] 0.2 1.0 1.0 0.2 0.5 0.8
```

where

```
purity <- sample(c("pure","high","medium","low"), 10000, replace = TRUE) 
key <- c("low", "medium", "high",  "pure")
value   <- c(0.2, 0.5,  0.8, 1.0)
```

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to use this code. Is object coef in in unname(setNames()) the vector of length five defined in my original post? Is it assumed to be a vector of length 10,000 containing no information (as 'coef<-rep(NA,10000)')?

Comment: It is a key/value pair for `purity/coef`

Comment: I see. I get the same results when I redefine objects purity and coef as:                   purity <- c("pure", "high", "medium", "low") ;
coef   <- c(1.0, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2)

Comment: @overcup In your post, purity` is defined twice.  if you are reassigning `purity` as shorter length, the old sample will get overwritten

Comment: The second 'purity' is meant to illustrate.

Comment: @overcup You may have done that to illustrate, but in reality, the ones you defined later with purity and coef are the key/value pairs which you want to match and replace the original vector

Comment: My point is that if you have other unique elements and you want to replace, create those `purity` of unique values and the corresponding values you want to replace in 'coef' or just without any object also, `c(medium = 0.5, high = 0.8, low = 0.2, pure = 1.0)[youroriginalpurityvector]`

Comment: @overcup I noticed that you had `high` defined twice, which I removed to make it unique

Comment: @overcup changed the object names to avoid any confusion